# Can I reference and instantiate other ink! smart contract more than once?

Tags: ink

Based on the [ink! Cross-Contract Calling documentation](https://ink.substrate.io/basics/cross-contract-calling/), I want to reference other smart contract and instantiate it more than once. That would be possible?

I tried to do it but when I execute the logic twice I get a `Duplicate Contract` error. I don't know if I have to send different parameters to salt_bytes() or if this is not possible right now with `ink`.

I let you an example of what I have been trying:

```
let new_contract = ContractRef::new(owner)
            .endowment(0)
            .code_hash(self.contract_hash)
            .salt_bytes(self.version.to_le_bytes())
            .instantiate()
            .expect("failed at instantiating the contract");
```

Thanks!

Comment: Does anybody know where I can find documentation on ContractRef? I am unsure where the methods such as .endowment() come from.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you use the same salt when instantiating for the second time? Looks to me like it might be the problem, since the salt is used to determine contract's account ID.

Comment: I tried modifying the salt and was successful. I was about to share it. Thank you!